# VBA : ColumnWidth is not working for the first columns

Tags: excel, vba, column-width

My problem is about VBA formating cells : I'm trying to put some text in cells depending on what my UserForm's texboxes has as values. The problem is that when a user put a long text, i wanted to adjust the columns width, i have tried all thoses codes, none of them work for the first column :

```
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 12
Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 12
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B1").Columns.AutoFit
```

Please also note that it only happen with the A column, the second and third column has their column width adjusted as i wanted with this code:

```
Columns("C:D").ColumnWidth = 12
Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 12
```

Any suggestion ?

[image: This is how it looks like...]

Comment: Do you have merged cells? That might mess it up.

Comment: @SJR yes my cells are merged, there's no way to increase the size of my columns wdith if it's merged then ?

Comment: My 2nd column is also merged but it works on it....

Comment: It might not be that, it's just that merged cells are generally a pain and best avoided.